# Google Drive synchronise other Folders on OS X?

Tags: macos, google-drive

Similar to [How to synchronize directories outside the Google Drive directory](https://superuser.com/questions/420343/google-drive-how-to-synchronize-directories-outside-gooogledrive-directory) but specific to OS X.

I have a folder in `Application Support` I want to be backed up on Google Drive. How can I make Google Drive add that folder as an extra thing to sync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a symlink tot that folder in your google driver folder.

```
cd ~/Google\ Drive
ln -s ~/Application\ Support
```

**Edit**:
Google drive doesn't support symlinks, so one solution I see is:

1. Boot in the recovery mode
2. Move your application support folder to google drive
3. Create a symlink to this folder in your home folder

Disclaimer: I didn't test it, but it should work.

Comment: You are right, I tried it now in Lion, it doesn't work, but you can do it the other way arroud, I edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

Right now my solution is to rsync the two directories in a cronjob. e.g.:

```
rsync -r "/Users/gak/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2" "/Users/gak/Google Drive/Configuration/"
```

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is probably a better alternative to rsync in this case, since it can do a two way rsync.